# How to set more colors in R?

Tags: r, colors

I would like to color my graph in R by 21 colors, so I set 21 colors:

```
palette(c(rgb(171,182,62,maxColorValue=255),rgb(158,88,203,maxColorValue=255),
          [...]
```

But when I use this command:

`scatter3d(x = red, y = green, z = blue, groups = C1class$V1,
          grid = FALSE, surface = FALSE)`

It give me an error:

```
Error in scatter3d.default(x = red, y = green, z = blue, groups = C1class$V1,  : 
  Number of groups (13) exceeds number of colors (8)
```

How to set the new palette to coloring the graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `car::scatter3d()` function ignores the palette by default.  If you want to use it with a 9 colour palette, you can set `surface.col=1:9` in your call.  Modifying lukeA's answer,

```
library(car)            
d <- Duncan
d$type <- as.factor(sample(1:9, nrow(d), TRUE))
palette(rainbow(9)) # Or use your own palette...
scatter3d(prestige ~ income + education | type, data = d, surface.col = 1:9, grid = FALSE, 
          surface = FALSE)
```